# 'There are two types of girl' or 'there are two types of girls'?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct:

'There are two types of girl' or 'there are two types of girls'?

Comment: In my opinion, the second option is more clear.  However, either option is acceptable in English.  It has to do with whether you're referring to "girl" as a generic noun or not.  "There are two types of woman" means that "womanhood" is divided into two parts.  It is somewhat awkward, and the preferred option would be to treat "women" or "girls" as plural.  "There are two types of women [girls]" explicitly says what it seems like you're trying to say.

Comment: *Girls* would be best for parallelism with the very, very common "there are two types of people".

Comment: For perspective and insight try out saying for two types of mouse/mice, child/children, wife/wives, goose/geese.